# Car following models

Tags: integration

I have one questions about car following models how its expression is integrated.
We have that ; 
$\ a_{n+1}(t+T)=\ \alpha\frac{v_n(t)-v_{n+1}(t)}{{x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)}} $

How come that the integral of expression above equals this:

$\int{\alpha\frac{v_n(t)-v_{n+1}(t)}{{x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)}}}dt = \alpha*ln(C*x^{(n)}(t)-x^{(n+1)}(t))  $

I have looked in many books, but they all just write the answer, not how it is calculated.

Comment: Please check your formulae. it looks like you're mixing some symbols. You're using $x_n$ and $x^{(n)}$; are they the same. What is $l_n$? You're also missing ay least one bracket in the last formula.

Also, are you sure there's a square in the denominator? Because when we check
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\big(\ln(x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)) \big)=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}(x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)) }{x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t) } = \frac{v_n(t)-v_{n+1}(t) }{x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t) } $$

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since velocity $v_n$ is a derivative of position $x_n$ you have

\begin{align} \int \alpha \frac{v_n(t)-v_{n+1}(t)}{x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)}dt &= \int \alpha \frac{\frac{d}{dt}\big(x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)\big)}{x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)}dt = \\
&= \int \alpha \frac{d}{dt}\ln\big(x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)\big)dt = \\
&= \alpha \ln\big(x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)\big) + C \end{align}
Using properties of the logarithm, it can also be written as
$$ \alpha \ln\big(x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)\big) + C = \alpha \ln\Big(\tilde C\big(x_n(t)-x_{n+1}(t)\big)\Big) $$
where $\tilde C = \exp(C/\alpha)$.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Finally a explanation!!. Probably need to refresh my basic math :) Thank you!